# Constrained minimization on complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, constraints

I want to solve the following constrained optimization problem
$$ \arg\min_X \| Y - X  \|_2^2 , \quad Y,X \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$$
$$ s.t. A X = 0 , \quad A \in \mathbb{C}^{N-2 \times N}$$

If I reduce the problem to the real case, I manage to find the solution using the Lagrangian :
$$ X= (I-A^H(AA^H)^{-1}A)Y $$

However, in the complex case, I can't get any solutions.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you meant $A^H$ in your text there

Comment: you expressed $X$ through $X$, while it can be okay in some cases, how you ensure the condition $AX=0$ is satisfied?

Comment: There was a typo in my text, I edited it.